# Solve recurrence relation $k_{i + 1} = (k_i + 2i + 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

**Question**: You can compute the indices for the probe sequence more efficiently by using the recurrence relation

$$k_{i + 1} = (k_i + 2i + 1) \bmod{n}$$

for $i \ge 0$ and $k_0 = k$. Derive this recurrence relation.

**Solution**: after iterative substitutions,

$$
\begin{align}
k_{i + 1} = (k_i + 2i + 1) \bmod{n}\\
\vdots\\
=jk_0+2ji+j \bmod{n}\\
=jk+2ji+j \bmod{n} , k_0=k
\end{align}
$$

**Problem**: not sure if this is correct as I found it's $k(i+1) = k(i) + 2j +1 \bmod{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$K_{i+1}-K_i=2i+1$$
Do telescopic summation:
$$\begin{aligned}
K_1-K_0&=1\\
K_2-K_1&=3\\
K_3-K_2&=5\\
K_4-K_3&=7\\
\vdots\\
K_{n-1}-K_{n-2}&=2n-3\\
K_n-K_{n-1}&=2n-1
\end{aligned}$$
Add all to get
$$K_n-K_0=n^2\implies K_n=n^2+k$$